# python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' in list

Tags: python, list, replace

```
#@ Row 1, Column 4: Invalid character value for cast specification @#
```

BCC,01,12697,2013-12-   12,1.0,2014004,CR,ACCOUN    TS PAYABLE,-86.23000,,2200-000-000,,    ,,,,True,,0,False,,,False,,,,,,0.00000,0.00000

I am trying to remove the tab in the date value and elsewhere in each row of data.

```
columndata = [str(items.replace('\t', '')) for items in list(row)]
```

However, this command returns the following error:

```
  File "apdetfac.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
  columndata = [str(items.replace('\t', '')) for items in list(row)]
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I tried converting items to str as follows str(items) in list(row) but that generated another error. What to do?

Comment: there might be missing values in your date column.
Try `[str(items.replace('\t', '')) if items else items for items in list(row)]`
Also, what is the row object? Is it 1 row of data? In that case you are not looping properly

Comment: give your full code.

Comment: It is data from Progress extracted using pyodbc. Im looping on                  
 for row in data:

Comment: I will try your suggestion Vivek

Comment: This is what I get now:  AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: here is full code:  with open('c:\\data\\factdata.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        print('Output table data\n')
        
    
        for row in data:
            columndata = [str(items.replace('\t', '')) if items else items for items in list(row)]
            wr.writerow(columndata)
        
    myfile.close()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

Comment: I believe your current code is only iterating through the columns of one row. Looks like `list(row)[3]` is the desired string you want to replace. So basically loop through all rows and replace the 4th element

Comment: @user1082748 you should update the code in the question. with your update, `str(list(row)[3]).replace('\t', '')` looks sufficient. No need to loop (unless you have more date columns

Comment: Please update the question with your full code.

Comment: columndata = [str(items.replace('\t', '')) for items in list(row)[3]]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Please **edit** your question and write in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell what data you have, but this gives the right sort of answer:

```
row_str = 'BCC,01,12697,2013-12-\t12,1.0,2014004,CR,ACCOUN\tTS PAYABLE,-86.23000,,2200-000-000,, ,,,,True,,0,False,,,False,,,,,,0.00000,0.00000'
# note the '\t' in date and ACCOUNTS

row = row_str.split(',')

columndata = [str(items.replace('\t', '')) for items in row]

print(columndata)
```

Output:

```
['BCC', '01', '12697', '2013-12-12', '1.0', '2014004', 'CR', 'ACCOUNTS PAYABLE', '-86.23000', '', '2200-000-000', '', ' ', '', '', '', 'True', '', '0', 'False', '', '', 'False', '', '', '', '', '', '0.00000', '0.00000']
```

Of course this list can be joined back into a string:

```
new_row = ','.join(columndata)
print(new_row)
```

Output:

```
BCC,01,12697,2013-12-12,1.0,2014004,CR,ACCOUNTS PAYABLE,-86.23000,,2200-000-000,, ,,,,True,,0,False,,,False,,,,,,0.00000,0.00000
```

Comment: rowStr = row.split(',')
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I converted row.split to str(row).split and rest of remains the same and it appears to be working.

Comment: Will you all know in a few once the million plus rows are processed. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "'BCC,01,12697,2013-12-\t12,1.0,2014004,CR,ACCOUN\tTS PAYABLE,-86.23000,,2200-000-000,, ,,,,True,,0,False,,,False,,,,,,0.00000,0.00000'"

print(','.join(map(lambda x: x.replace('\t',''), data.split(','))))
>>>'BCC,01,12697,2013-12-12,1.0,2014004,CR,ACCOUNTS PAYABLE,-86.23000,,2200-000-000,, ,,,,True,,0,False,,,False,,,,,,0.00000,0.00000'
```